# Get the file extension from images picked from gallery or camera, as string

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery

I want to get as string the image extension (for example "jpg", "png", "bmp" ecc.) of the images loaded from the gallery or picked from the camera.

I have used a method in this form to load images from the gallery

```
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
....
private void selectPicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
....
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PICTURE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    .........
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the latest update and the right answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12473985/10078629

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
 filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".")); // Extension with dot .jpg, .png
```

**or**

```
 filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); // Without dot jpg, png
```

Comment: after   String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

Comment: I have tried with no success... what is exactly "strname"??

Could you give me more details looking the method that I have used?? Thanks.

Comment: see my updated answer and also see for .jpg or jpg...and check if(null!=filepath&&filepath.trim().lenght()!=0){...}

Answer (score 46):

I know it's pretty late but for those who still have a problem when getContentResolver().getType(uri) returns null when path contains white spaces. This also solves the problem when an image is opened via File Manager instead of gallery. This method returns the extension of the file (jpg, png, pdf, epub etc..).

```
 public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String extension;

    //Check uri format to avoid null
    if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        //If scheme is a content
        final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        extension = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(context.getContentResolver().getType(uri));
    } else {
        //If scheme is a File
        //This will replace white spaces with %20 and also other special characters. This will avoid returning null values on file name with spaces and special characters.
        extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath())).toString());

    }

    return extension;
}
```

Comment: String mimeType = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);  //get value: "image/jpg";                                                                                                       String extension = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(mimeType); // get null

Comment: Turning a file Uri to a File and then to a Uri again is a bit redundant.

Comment: Because I need to parse spaces and special characters i.e space should be %20. Using new File() on the uri path will automatically parse those special characters. If you remove this part, this code will throw an error on file names that have spaces or special characters

Answer (score 20):

```
getContentResolver().getType(theReceivedUri);
```

The above snippet gets you the type as "media/format"

Answer (score 9):

Dear Friend we can find the extension of any file, image, video and any docs.
for this.

First, we will create a method `GetFileExtension` which we want to call to find the extension of a file, image, data and docs. Here I took a variable named:

```
Uri videouri = data.getData();
```

in `OnActivity` Result then I invoke it in,

```
onclick(View view)
{
    GetFileExtension(videouri);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Exten: "+GetFileExtension(videouri), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now make a Class to class `GetFileExtension`:

```
// Get Extension
public String GetFileExtension(Uri uri)
{
        ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();

        // Return file Extension
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
}
```

Due to this method we can find out the extension of any file in java and in android.
I'm 100 % sure it will work for you all who are making corporate App.
If you like then vote for me..

Answer (score 8):

you have multiple choice to get extension of file:like:

1-`String filename = uri.getLastPathSegment();` see this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getLastPathSegment())

2- you can use this code also

```
 filePath .substring(filePath.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
```

but this not good aproch.

3-if you have URI of file then use this Code

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
    MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE };
```

4-if you have URL then  use this code

```
public static String getMimeType(String url) {
String type = null;
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
if (extension != null) {
    type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
}
return type;}
```

Answer (score 7):

For "content://" sheme

```
fun Uri.getFileExtension(context: Context): String? {
    return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
        .getExtensionFromMimeType(context.contentResolver.getType(this))
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this should get you to where you want (I haven't tried it, just read a bit around and I think it works).

```
Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, 
                           MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME};
Cursor cursor =
     getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    int fileNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[1]);
    String fileName = cursor.getString(fileNameIndex);
    // Here we get the extension you want
    String extension = fileName.replaceAll("^.*\\.", ""); 
    .........
}
cursor.close();
```

Comment: No (at least pretty sure). `MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME` has the filename without extension. The only place in that database that includes the extension is `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA`

Comment: The `The data stream for the file`, hmm? Then the documentation is crappy.

Comment: meh, I am wrong. DISPLAY_NAME has the extension included, TITLE was the column where it is stripped - just checked in the db. In DATA you have the full path.

Comment: Regarding `DISPLAY_NAME` and `TITLE`: The filename is only used as a [default](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.3_r1/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java#2605) value if there is nothing better available (e.g. via `MediaScanner`). The only safe place to get the filename is DATA. That has to be the real filepath.

Comment: @Boris

I have tried to use this code but doesn't work ...the extension string results null

Answer (score 0):

if you get `content://media` Uris as result and you want the extension then you have to query the database as you do and extract if from `filePath`. E.g. with [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/ExtractFileExtension.htm)

To get the filename out of a full path the simplest solution is

```
String filename = (new File(filePath)).getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should use `MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE`

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split string to strings array and get last index of it

```
 String[] fileArr = picturePath.split("\\.");
    
 String fileExtension = fileArr[fileArr.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it using the Cursor. Here you can get not only the file type

```
val contentResolver = context.contentResolver

fun setInfoFile(contentResolver: ContentResolver, uri : Uri) {
    val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null)
    
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        val type = contentResolver.getType(uri).toString() // !!! return MIME types
        val fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))
        val bytes = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE))
        cursor.close()
    }
}
```

Here's how I get the type from the MIME-type

```
fun String.getMimeTypeDescription(): String {
    val type =  when (this) {
        "application/msword" -> "doc"
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" -> "docx"
        "application/vnd.ms-excel" -> "xls"
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" -> "xlsx"
        else -> this
    }.split("/")

    return type.last()
}
```