# How I can get the mime type of a file having its Uri?

Tags: android, uri, mime-types

I have a List of Uris obtained with the Gallery and the Camera. These Uris are like this: `content://media/external/images/media/94`. How I can get its mime type?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

You can try

```
ContentResolver cR = context.getContentResolver();
MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String type = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
```

**Edit :**

```
mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri))
```

returns -> "jpeg"

```
cR.getType(uri);
```

returns "image/jpeg" that is the expected value.

Comment: ````mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri))```` returns me ````"jpeg"```` but ````cR.getType(uri)```` returns ````"image/jpeg"```` that is the expected value.

Comment: This is not working for some devices..Is there any alternative?

Comment: @AditiParikh [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31691791/7196681)  works for me...

Comment: @BraisGabin I'm trying to read in a .csv file. For some reason I get "text/csv" for `cR.getType(uri)` but for `ime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));` I get null. Is .csv just not supported or something?

Comment: No, it's not supported. You can see a list of the currently supported extensions in this [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java).

Comment: How is this the accepted answer when it uses a method that returns extension of the file while OP is asking about the mime type?

Answer (score 38):

This method returns the extension of the file (jpg, png, pdf, epub etc..).

```
 public static String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String extension;

    //Check uri format to avoid null
    if (uri.getScheme().equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        //If scheme is a content
        final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        extension = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(context.getContentResolver().getType(uri));
    } else {
        //If scheme is a File
        //This will replace white spaces with %20 and also other special characters. This will avoid returning null values on file name with spaces and special characters.
        extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath())).toString());

    }

    return extension;
}
```

Comment: Its working for me.. I did follow https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: @Aaron Thanks. It works perfectly for non-english file names.

Comment: can you explain why u need Uri.fromFile(new File(uri.getPath()))       when the method params includes a Uri

Comment: Because I need to parse spaces and special characters i.e space should be %20. Using new File() on the uri path will automatically parse those special characters. If you remove this part, this code will throw an error on file names that have spaces or special characters

Answer (score 22):

for `Content` `Uri`.

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
mimeType = cr.getType(contentUri);
```

for `File` `Uri`.

```
String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileUri
            .toString());
mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
            fileExtension.toLowerCase());
```

for Both, works for `Content` as well as `File`.

```
public String getMimeType(Context context, Uri uri) {
    String mimeType = null;
    if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(uri.getScheme())) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        mimeType = cr.getType(uri);
    } else {
        String fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(uri
                .toString());
        mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
                fileExtension.toLowerCase());
    }
    return mimeType;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(), it seems not to be able to handle all filenames. For example, on my emulator, photos taken with the camera contain commas and spaces in the filename, which causes this method to return an empty String. I recommend falling back to manual parsing if the method call failed (get the index of the last '.' and use it to take the substring)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of this:

```
String type = mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
```

Do this:

```
String type = cR.getType(uri);
```

And you will get this: `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Only works for content uris (content://). Doesn't work for file uris (file://)

Comment: Actually the path doesn't matter for the getType. It's simply the case that the other end of the intent needs to have explicitly set the type for the intent. Often times this doesn't happen for paths.

Answer (score 4):

Return "image/jpeg" for example

```
fun Uri.getMimeType(context: Context): String? {
    return when (scheme) {
        ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT -> context.contentResolver.getType(this)
        ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE -> MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(
            MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(toString()).toLowerCase(Locale.US)
        )
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will parrot the answer of Bhavesh with Kotlin extension and return type of `okhttp3.MediaType`:

```
fun Uri.mimeType(contentResolver: ContentResolver)
        : MediaType? {
    if (scheme.equals(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT)) {
        // get (image/jpeg, video/mp4) from ContentResolver if uri scheme is "content://"
        return contentResolver.getType(this)?.toMediaTypeOrNull()
    } else {
        // get (.jpeg, .mp4) from uri "file://example/example.mp4"
        val fileExtension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(toString())
        // turn ".mp4" into "video/mp4"
        return MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                .getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension.toLowerCase(Locale.US))
                ?.toMediaTypeOrNull()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for kotlin this function will work

```
fun getMime(uri : Uri, context: Context) : String?{
    val cr = context.contentResolver
    return cr.getType(uri)
}
```